# Split csv according to field and create Subdirectory then save :

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to split a csv file according to the 2nd "field". For instance the csv file contains:

Input.csv :: /c/Test/

```
aaa,K1,ppp
ddd,M3,ppp
bbb,K1,ppp
ccc,L2,ppp
```

This file would be split into three separate files according to second field.

First file: /c/Test/K1/K1.csv

```
aaa,K1,ppp
bbb,K1,ppp
```

Second file: /c/Test/M3/M3.csv

```
ddd,M3,ppp
```

Third file: /c/Test/L2/L2.csv

```
ccc,L2,ppp
```

Tried the below command to split file based on 2nd column and working fine, however the splitted files on the same directory 
Like:  /c/Test/K1.csv and /c/Test/M3.csv etc ..

```
awk -F, '{ print > $2".csv"}' Input.csv
```

Have tried the below command is not working to create subdirectory and incomplete , please help ..

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { system("mkdir -p $2") } { print > $10".csv"}' Input.csv

awk -F, '{ print >/system("mkdir -p $2")/ $2".txt"}' Input.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{ system("mkdir -p "$2); print > $2"/"$2".csv"}' Input.csv
```

Assuming your Input.csv contains:

```
aaa,K1,ppp
ddd,M3,ppp
bbb,K1,ppp
ccc,L2,ppp
```

And this file is in `/c/Test/` and you want directories to be created in `/c/Test/`.

The main difference with your attempt is `system("mkdir -p "$2)` i.e put `$2` outside of quotes. This will concatenate `"mkdir -p "` and the value of `$2`. When you put it inside quotes it becomes literal `$2` and the value is not available to `mkdir` command.

After the directory is created, it prints output to the desired file which has the path `$2"/"$2".csv"`

Comment: +1 for the compact awk one-liner. one note: if the  count of  uniq `$2` is big, don't use `print >`, instead, use `print >>` and `close($2.csv)` after appending.. otherwise may hit "too many opened file" like error.

Comment: @Kent , Thanks for the suggestion , is it like this command : awk -F, '{ system("mkdir -p "$2); print >> $2"/"$2".csv" ; close ($2.csv) }' Input.csv
    kindly correct if any modification required

Comment: @user3350223 it should be `close($2"/"$2".csv")` I was a bit lazy... sorry. better save the filename into a variable, to avoid the dup codes

Comment: Dear Kent, started learning awk and read this forum recently only, kindly elaborate or possible provide syntax to save filename into variable once you get some time ..

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in bash using `read`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read a b c; do
    mkdir -p "$b" && echo "$a,$b,$c" >> "$b/$b.csv"
done < Input.csv
```

`read` splits the input line on the input field separator (`IFS`). It makes the directory based on the name of the second column and `echo`s the line to the relevant file.

Or if you can use bash arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
    IFS=","
    while read -a l
    do 
        mkdir -p "${l[1]}" && echo "${l[*]}" >> "${l[1]}/${l[1]}.csv"
    done < Input.csv
)
```

The use of `( )` means that the original value of `$IFS` is preserved once the script has run.

Comment: @user3350223 Not a problem, I know you were trying to do this using awk but I thought it may be useful to show how this could be done in bash.